# jQuery/js submit form on click

Tags: php, jquery

I can't submit the form after disable the submit button.
I make a jquery code to prevent multiple submit it's work but the form doesn't send the POST request.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var enblereg = function(e) {
    $(e).removeAttr("disabled");
}

$("#goRegister").click(function() {
$(this.form).submit();
    var reg = this;
    $('#reg').submit();
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(function() { enblereg(reg) }, 2000);
});
});
```

php:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['goRegister'])) { echo "send";} ?>
    <form action="?" method="POST" id="reg">
        <h6>Full Name: <?php echo $fnamerr; ?></h6>
        <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fullname;?>">
        <h6>Email: <?php echo $emailerr; ?></h6>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <h6>Re-enter Email: <?php echo $aemailerr; ?></h6>
        <input type="text" name="aemail" value="<?php echo $aemail;?>">
        <h6>password: <?php echo $passworderr; ?></h6>      
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <h6>Re-enter password: <?php echo $apassworderr; ?></h6>        
        <input type="password" name="apassword">
        <h6>Birthday: <?php echo $bdayerr;?></h6>   
        <?php include ("/incs/birthdayinc.php");?>
        <h6>Gender: <?php echo $gendererr; ?></h6>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><font size="1"><b>Female</b></font>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"><font size="1"><b>Male</b></font><br>
        <input type="submit" name="goRegister" id="goRegister" value="Register">
      </form>
```

without the jQuery the post work, I tried to solve it with "ONCLICK":

this.form.submit() - doesn't work

what should I need to add in jQuery to submit the form before disable the submit button ?

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying not to use the jQuery features, and you are trying to use plain Vanilla JavaScript. You'll find that it won't always work the way you thought it would. I suggest not using jQuery at all if you are interested in JavaScript.

Comment: @RPM, jQuery is nothing but JavaScript... that's not really his problem.

Comment: Vanilla Javascript (library/framework free javascript.) is different than the abstraction jQuery provides in it's framework.

Comment: @RPM, lol... if you say so.  JavaScript is JavaScript.  jQuery is a JavaScript Framework.

Comment: Do you not understand what I am trying to express with the words I've typed? It is a fact that writing JavaScript without a framework is different than using jQuery.

Comment: I think Ill use Session prevent multiple submit, I get tired of this JS.

Comment: @RPM, yes, writing JavaScript for a framework is somewhat different than writing JavaScript without a framework... that's the whole point.  But "vanilla JavaScript" is such a ridiculous term:  [vanilla-js.com](http://vanilla-js.com)  (_it's a spoof_)

Comment: @Sparky I'm completely aware of the spoof. That is why I further explained my own definition of it in the parenthesis. I didn't think you would think that I believed there was a real framework called Vanilla JavaScript. It's a term I used in the context of jQuery to explain to people the difference between certain functionality in JQuery and framework-free JavaScript.

Comment: @RPM, We essentially agree.  I only take exception when people make blanket statements.

Comment: @RPM, I never accused you of thinking "Vanilla" was a real framework.  The point of the spoof is to make fun of using nonsensical terminology. After all, we don't have "vanilla" PHP or "vanilla" whatever-language-minus-a-framework.

Comment: @Sparky You're right. You made me aware of my nonsensical use of the phrase. In the context of JavaScript without a framwork, I will not longer be using the phrase "Vanilla JavaScript" to refer to it, but rather "framework free JavaScript"

Answer (score 1):

I think the jQuery code for the process would be like this

```
$(this.form).submit();
```

This would submit the form for you. If it doesn't actually trigger the event. Then you can capture the form and submit it directly using the id of it.

```
id="reg"
```

So, it would be

```
$('#reg').submit();
```

Comment: Then trigger the submit for the form, using its own ID.

Comment: I tried this $('#reg').submit(); and its not work the php doesnt sho the err msg when I post the form emty if I remove the jQuery the php code work .

Comment: You need to check the value too, something like this `if($('somefield').val() == '') { alert('sorry, input the value first'); } `. This is a conditional field, used to check for the values of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Do this...  The form has id of #reg.  So simply use $('#reg').submit();

```
$("#goRegister").click(function() {
  var reg = this;
  $('#reg').submit();
  $(this).attr("disabled", true);
  setTimeout(function() { enblereg(reg) }, 2000);
 });
```

**EDIT**

Updated for ajax submit

```
 $("#goRegister").click(function() {
  var reg = $(this);
  var form = $('#reg').serialize();
  var url = "Whereveryouareposting.php";
  //Submit ajax form
  $.post(url,form,function(data){
     //This is where you could send back error messages or success from the server
     // To dictate wether to hide the button, or display errors.
     // Ie On success....do this...

     $(this).attr("disabled", true);
     setTimeout(function() { enblereg(reg) }, 2000);

     // On error, send a message packet with the errors, and loop through it to attach error 
     //messages to fields
  });

 });
```

Comment: Do what? Are you going to explain why this should work?

Comment: Isnt it kinda self explanatory.  The form, named #reg, is now being submitted

Comment: If it was self explanatory the OP wouldn't have asked the question ;)

Comment: It's is not working .. when I post the form without filing the fields the php code doesn't show me the err msg i created if the form post empty ..

Comment: @RUJordan I meant, the answer I posted is kinda self exlanatory.  Meaning it kinda speaks for itself.  First the code had no submit(), now it does

Comment: @user3746250 Why wouldn't your php code be working on the other side.  Submitting the form through jquery submit(), is the exact same as if you just submit the form empty anyways.  There should be no difference.  Unless you're doing some sort of javascript empty form checking.  Which in that case, you need to run that before submitting.

Comment: Also...I just realized you probably want to do an ajax form submit, so that the form submits in the background and then your button becomes disabled.  The way this is working.  It will submit, and then refresh the page.  Which will in turn reload the button as enabled.  Not disabled

Comment: The button becomes disable after I click on him but that "echo" line from php doesn't work: if (isset($_POST['goRegister'])) { echo "send";} if I remove the jQuery and submit the form than the echo line work